# Java Button not appearing in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

The buttons are not appearing in my JPanel, only if when I pass the mouse on the Invisible Button...

That's not my code. So, my code seems alright, but didnt appear in my JPanel... I just tried to revalidate and repaint the JPanel and nothing happened...

```
for (int i; i < 5; i++) {
  JButton button = new JButton();
  button.setText("" + i);
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 

       System.out.print("\n Test: " + ae.getActionCommand());

     } 
  });
  button.setSize(60,20);
  button.setLocation(100, 140);
  button.setVisible(true);
  this.add(button);
  this.revalidate();
  this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: What layout manager does the panel have?

Comment: @kihero i'm using the default layout...

Comment: Wait, is your for loop going to work without giving an intial value to i?

Comment: @JeremyD its java... when u put int i, the java put i value to 0...

Comment: I still think it is bad practice to not initialize it. And thank you I know this is Java :)

Comment: Hmmm, but why you think better to put the value of i? @JeremyD

Comment: I don't know it sounds logical to me to give an initial value to your i, but anyway that's not the solution to your issue.

Comment: The default is `FlowLayout`; it *should* work, assuming the layout manager of the component containing that panel is giving it enough space. Otherwise it seems that there's not enough code to tell what's wrong.

Comment: What does this refer to?

Comment: @kiheru i'm putting the button into an JPanel ... When i pass the mouse that visible.. It seens like Button didnt have more focus than the JPanel...

Comment: How to close the Post? I got it... Just put button.requestFocusInWindow(); in the last line of method.. and the button now visible... :)

Comment: There are any number of reasons this might occur, can you provide a runnable example for us to play with

Comment: i put the solution below... Just an focus problem... And @JeremyD i got the code, heres the for of my code: for "(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)".. :PPP.. I Put an value to i in my code :)))...

Comment: as said by MadProgrammer, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is the way to let us know what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have that problem...

Just put:
button.requestFocusInWindow();  // in last line of method...

Like that:

```
for (int i; i < 5; i++) {
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setText("" + i);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 

   System.out.print("\n Test: " + ae.getActionCommand());

 } 
});
button.setSize(60,20);
button.setLocation(100, 140);
button.setVisible(true);
this.add(button);
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
button.requestFocusInWindow();
```

}

Comment: `Just put: button.requestFocusInWindow(); // in last line of method...` - it it NOT necessary to request focus on a component in order for the component to be displayed. You still a problem with your code and since you refuse to post a `SSCCE` - you will never find out the proper solution.

Comment: agreed.  the validate/repaint/requestfocus shouldn't be necessary at all.  especially not inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You're setting all 5 buttons to have the exact same location:

```
button.setLocation(100, 140);
```

you shouldn't need that at all, let the layout manager for the panel handle that for you.

Comment: Thank you, its my fault in that code, but in my original code i put an math algoritm to have any distance :)).. Ty for help...

Comment: `setLocation` is a problem, but calling `revalidate` would trigger the layout manager to layout the components, therefore negating what `setLocation` has done, so I doubt that this is the either the (main) problem or a solution...

Comment: it depends on what the layout manager is.  If there is one, yes, it should do that.  If there isn't one (you're doing all the layout yourself), this would be *an* issue.

Comment: You did not show us your code, you need to include the entire code so that we can read what you are trying to do. Otherwise it would be hard to tell what you are missing. We cannot tell if you attempted to add the button class to the Jpanel or not, or if you are missing a frame to display the button. Add the entire code.